# Unity2D click and go to the mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls

I'm making a game where you are in control of a Worm. The controls are simple: You click and the worm goes to where you click... at least that's what I attempted to do.

Its very easy to cheat because if you hold the mouse in one place the worm begins to glitch out and holds still. (Once you click, the worm should not be able to stop until the next level is reached)

Here's a video:
https://youtu.be/LIcqvgacI1s

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 mousePosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 direction;
    public float moveSpeed = 100f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            direction = (mousePosition - rb.position).normalized;
            Vector2 lookDir = mousePosition - rb.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
            rb.rotation = angle;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * moveSpeed, direction.y * moveSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

If more info is needed, I'd be happy to supply it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It glitches because it stops, it needs to keep carrying on in that direction until you tell it to change.  Why set the rb.position to itself if not mouse down?

Comment: I thought resetting the position would help but it did not. This is my first game and I'm just now learning C#.

Comment: Odd, your fixed code looks like the code in the question did at the start...

Comment: I changed the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 mousePosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 direction;
    public float moveSpeed = 100f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            direction = (mousePosition - rb.position).normalized;
            Vector2 lookDir = mousePosition - rb.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
            rb.rotation = angle;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * moveSpeed, direction.y * moveSpeed);
        } else
        {
            rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x, rb.position.y);
        }
    }
}
```